# How to make entire table cell clickable when it has a hyperlink - using bootstrap v3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, html-table

This is how i am trying but it does not work

The only thing is, it gets 100% width equal to table cell width but the height does not change. How can i make the entire table cell clickable?

Here what i do

```
  <td><a href="Default.aspx?ClusterId=1" class="btn-full">click here</a></td>
```

And this is inside my CSS file

```
    .btn-full {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The bootstrap version i use is v 3.3.6

I am testing with latest version chrome : Version 51.0.2704.106 m

[image]

Comment: Try to add class="btn btn-default" to <td>

Comment: @onedevteam.com tried still doesnt work :D https://i.snag.gy/uqIHT9.jpg

Comment: and remove btn-full from <a>?

Comment: @onedevteam.com just tried does not change here : https://i.snag.gy/ShWlQ2.jpg

Answer (score 3):

In your case, since other td in same row has more content, you need to make all your td contents as equal height. Below code should work for above issue.

```
td{overflow:hidden;
   .btn-full {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:-1000px;
    padding: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: but this can pretty much break responsiveness right?

Comment: It will not break responsiveness. It will act normally how a table works. Just that your td content will be of equal height.

Answer (score 1):

Possible with this.

```css
td{
  position:relative;
}
td a{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10em;
  margin: -10em;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>this is heading of cell 1</td>
    <td>this is heading of cell 2</td>
    <td>this is heading of cell 3</td>
    <td>this is heading of cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one<br>one</td>
    <td><a href="#">Two</a></td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><a href="#">Two</a></td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><a href="#">Two</a></td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><a href="#">Two</a></td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><a href="#">Two</a></td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><a href="#">Two</a></td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><a href="#">Two</a></td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: well i still need to keep responsiveness in mobile experience. will this break it?

Comment: No it will not because `<a>` is placed according to its `<td>` and `<td>` will be there in responsive also no matter about the size.

Comment: yes i just tried but this breaks vertical align middle :(

Comment: no i mean i want to display the text vertical alignment middle . here what happens : http://orig11.deviantart.net/8fcf/f/2016/181/f/f/aa_by_monstermmorpg-da86t7y.png

Comment: ty for updated answer. still only text part is clickable :D https://i.snag.gy/RtVHkQ.jpg if you run your snippet and analyze by chrome you will see the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
 
td a{
      width:100%;
      line-height:40px;
      display:inline-block;
      vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>heading 1</td>
    <td>heading 2 with extra space</td>
    <td>heading 3</td>
    <td>heading 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><a href="#">Two</a></td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><a href="#">Two</a></td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: height is still same. i want height of the hyperlink to be same as table cell height

Comment: Updated the answer @MonsterMMORPG