# Using Click Events to Hyperlink Table Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to HTML/CSS/JS/etc, and have the following objective: I am trying to effectively hyperlink individual rows in tables. I am aware that this is not inherently possible, but have found that the solution I prefer most is simply using onclick methods. However...

Is there a way to distinguish mouse buttons for different reactions? Effectively, I am trying to mimic the usual reaction of mouse clicks for a link e.g., left click opens the link in the current tab, middle click opens the link in a new tab, and right click opens up the context menu for links.

What I know:

- I can open the link in the current tab with a simple link, or in a new tab/window by using window.open
- I can have it react to only the left click with onclick, or to all three with onmousedown or onmouseup

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish my goal with the following solution:

[How to make entire table cell clickable when it has a hyperlink - using bootstrap v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097604/how-to-make-entire-table-cell-clickable-when-it-has-a-hyperlink-using-bootstra)

All I did after it was then stylize the hyperlink text as desired.